# Kerberos аутентификация в Oracle

Tags: windows, oracle, kerberos

Есть Windows Server 2008 r2 с доменом `myora.local` и AD. На нём стоит сервер БД Oracle. Есть клиент на Win7.
На сервере:

-в файле C:\krb\krb.conf

```
MYORA.LOCAL
MYORA.LOCAL myora.local admin server
```

-в файле C:\krb\krb5.realms

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm=MYORA.LOCAL
[realms]
MYORA.LOCAL= {
    kdc=DomainController.myora.local:88
}
[domain_realm]
.local.myora=MYORA.LOCAL
```

-sqlnet.ora

```
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CONF= c:\krb\krb.conf
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_REALMS = c:\krb\krb5.realms
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CC_NAME = C:\krb\v5srvtab
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (BEQ, TCPS, NTS, KERBEROS5)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CONF_MIT = TRUE
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_KERBEROS5_SERVICE = krbtgt
```

okinit работает для Kefir@MYORA.LOCAL (имя пользователя на компе-сервере)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На клиенте проделываю те же самые шаги (кроме sqlnet.ora), но okinit выдаёт ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
От локального имени user1 не находит, а по имени компьютера проблемы с кредами.
Что нужно исправить?

Comment: Хорошо, что вы продублировали вопрос на англ. стеке. Здесь не думаю, что кто-то сможет помочь. Там плюсанул, на оценённые вопросы охотней отвечают.

Comment: спасибо вам большое)